# Error page when making tag wikis suggestions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tagwiki

It recently happened to me a couple of times that I want to add a tag wiki suggestion, but only get the general *Opps* error page *after* submitting the edit form. The tag wikis is question were previously empty. It happened just now with the `url` tag.

Between these occasions I was at least once able to submit one successfully, so it doesn't seems to be a permanent error.

Did anyone made the same experience? I wonder if this is a real error or just some funny "access denied" message. Maybe there is already a suggestion for this tag wiki in the queue or something.

---

This morning (22th Feb) it worked again. I will wait until it reappears before reporting it to the SO/SX people.

Comment: I've been submitting quite a few tag wikis these days, and I never had a problem like this.

Comment: Again a case for meta.SO, I guess.

Comment: @Hendrik: You are right, but I wanted to discuss it first here to figure out if its me or the site. About meta.SO: they point you now (again) to meta.SX for all SX related things. For a while meta.SX was only for the v1.0 SXs.

Comment: Let me know if this issue returns, I made a few fixes around tag wikis in the last few days

Comment: I have edited previously empty tags in the last year without problems. Maybe this is fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. I have edited at lest ten previously empty tag wikis since I joined (which is after this question was posted) and I have never noticed this problem.